# Send dynamic data to Header function in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

As I need to get some dynamic content to my page header. So, let me know the way to send data through parameters. I have not found how to call, send parameters to the header function. Please help me to solve this..

1. How can I call Header() function with parameters?
2. I need to send data through parameters to Header() function.
   [image]

Comment: Avoid to paste image instead of code....That mush of lazy you are? Why we want to help you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting a new property of the TCPDF class. The property will need to be set before the `AddPage()` method is called for the next page. Before creating a new property you may want to check the [TCPDF documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/)  for an existing property that may be useful. Searching “get” will allow you to quickly find them.

Be careful to give the new property a unique name, so you don’t change an existing property of TCPDF. You may want to include a check for the property in case one were to be added in a future version.

Setting a parameter of the `Header()` method is more difficult because it is called through a series of other methods (`AddPage()`, `startPage()`, `setHeader()`).

### Example

This example sets a new string for each page header with the new `CustomHeaderText` property. The example will run inside the TCPDF examples directory.

```php
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF
{
    public function Header()
    {
        $this->Write(0, $this->CustomHeaderText);
    }
}
$pdf = new MYPDF();
$pdf->CustomHeaderText = "Header Page 1";
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', 30, '<p>Page 1 Content</p>', 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

$pdf->CustomHeaderText = "Header Page 2";
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', 30, '<p>Page 2 Content</p>', 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a new property in your extended class MYPDF in this example

```html
<?php 
require 'tcpdf.php';
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    protected $company;

    public function setCompany($var){
        $this->company = $var;
    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // setCompany Text
        $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->company, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

To access this

```html
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setCompany("My Company");
```